# glyphicon is not displayed at all

Tags: django, positioning, html, display

I'm trying to build a web page. After I added the first glyphicon it worked just fine, but then I tried to add another one in order to enable to delete things for the user. But second glyphicon is not displayed. 
I do not understand why this happens.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head class="page-header">
        <title>WebPage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'static/css/Auswertung_app.css' %}">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <a href="{% url 'add_machine' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_machine' %}" class="top-menu-waste"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-sorted-waste"></span></a>
            <h1><a href="/">WebPage</a></h1>
        </div>
        base
        <div>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my .css file:

```
.top-menu, .top-menu:hover, .top-menu:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    font-size: 26pt;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.top-menu-waste, .top-menu-waste:hover, .top-menu-waste:visited{
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    font-size: 26pt;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `glyphicons-sorted-waste` is not a valid glyphicon icon class. You can find all the valid icon classes here - http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glyphicons` and `glyphicons-sorted-waste` are not valid glyphicon icon classes. You can only use those provided by bootstrap. You can find them all here http://getbootstrap.com/components/

The format should be consistent or it would not render the icons. The first one(glyphicon glyphicon-plus) is right/valid but the second(glyphicons glyphicons-sorted-waste) is not.

If you need a 'delete' icon, the right icon class could be `glyphicon-remove` or `glyphicon-minus`

**Usage:**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
```